# WordPress pagination seems to be ignored

Tags: php, wordpress

My 'older entries' link is not working. Can someone help to check it? Because I can't find it.

My website is http://prestasijunior.org/news/. That's where the link is not working.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    //query posts
        query_posts(
            array(
            'post_type'=> 'post',
            'paged'=>$paged
        ));
    ?>

<?php query_posts("showposts=1")?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'entry') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>       

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php
// Show a selected number of posts per row
$posts_per_row = 2;
$posts_per_page = 8;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
   'paged' => $paged,
);
query_posts($args);
query_posts('offset=1');
if (have_posts()) {
   while (have_posts()) {
      the_post();
      if ((++$post_counter % $posts_per_row) == 1  || $posts_per_row == 1) {
         if ($post_counter > 1) {
            echo "</div><!-- End of post_row -->\n";  // End previous row
         }
         echo "<div class='post_row'>\n";  // Start a new row
      }
      echo "<div class='post_class'>\n";  // Start one post
      // Output post data here
      echo "<div class='loop-entry-jmy'>\n";
      echo "<div class='loop-entry-date-j'>\n";the_time('j');echo "</div>\n";
      echo "<div class='loop-entry-date-m'>\n";the_time('M');echo "</div>\n";
      echo "<div class='loop-entry-date-y'>\n";the_time('Y');echo "</div>\n";
      echo "</div>\n";
      echo "<a href='". get_permalink() ."' id='news-title-2'>";the_title();echo "</a>";
      echo "<div class='p-excerpt'>\n";the_excerpt();echo "</div>\n";
      echo "</div><!-- End of post_class -->\n";  // End of post
   } ?>

   </div><!-- End of post_row -->
   <div class='clear'></div>
   <div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries »') ?></div>
   </div>
<?php } else {
   // Code for no posts found
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Does the "Newer Entries" button do anything? Has the "Older Entries" button ever worked? Does `query_posts()` take the prev/next buttons into account? How do these buttons affect the query string?

Comment: both newer and older entries buttons are not working. When I click it, it always shows the same content as prestasijunior.org/news .

Comment: However, the links do change the query string, right? I guess you need to manually detect the page number, and supply that to `query_posts()`. I don't know how to do that, but it will be in the WP manual.

Comment: Ah, is that what `get_query_var()` does? Echo the `$paged` variable out and see if it changes.

Comment: And.... why do you have two `query_posts()` in succession? Won't the `offset=1` version overwrite the results of the one immediately before?

Comment: Because I want to show the bigger news for the latest news, and then for the rest it will become smaller. Is there any other way to do that? I will try your suggestion above.

Comment: No no no - you're referring to the second call of `query_posts()`, which is fine, since you then show that post. I'm referring to calls three and four, one after the other, and one of which is likely to be redundant.

Comment: What does the first call to `query_posts()` do?

Comment: Ok, So what should I do now? I still don't get it.

Comment: Do you mean `<?php
    //query posts
        query_posts(
            array(
            'post_type'=> 'post',
            'paged'=>$paged,
        ));
    ?>`

It was already there, the default one.

Comment: OK, you have four calls to this function, and I think you only need two. Do you understand what it does? I'm not a WP expert, but I think it sets up your query to specify which posts/pages to fetch. You only need two queries - one for the single large item fetch, and one for the paginated block. Yes, the one whose code you have supplied is the first one, and that's what I mean by the first one. Try taking it out and see if the page stays the same. Then also take out the `query_posts('offset=1')` one too, and again check.

Comment: Just did that and nothing happen. Still the same as before.

Comment: Right, get debugging then! What is the difference between the `paged` and `offset` keys? If you don't immediately know, check in the manual. You may need to try adding `offset` to the args array. Try that in your code, and supply numbers manually (1, 2, ...) to see what difference it makes. (My guess is `paged` is boolean and `offset` is integer, but that's where the debugging comes in).

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. *my bad*. I change the offset value, but on it changed to my first page of news and second page. Still showing the same page.